# Как вывести значение из массива?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив `items` :

```
0: {id: "805", category: 'Wear'}

1: {id: "804", category: 'Hats'}
```

Как мне вывести из этого массива значение `category`. С помощью `foreach` или `for...in`?

```
    success: function (data) {
    var category_list = data.carts.items;
    category_list.forEach(function(item) {
    alert(item.descr);
},
```

Comment: а ещё есть for..of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
items = []

items[0] = {id: "805", category: 'Wear'}
items[1] = {id: "804", category: 'Hats'}
```

Первый способ:

```
console.log(items[0].category);
```

Второй способ:

```
console.log(items[0]['category']);
```

И в цикле:

```
items.forEach((obj) => {
    console.log(obj.category)
})

for(index in items){
    console.log(items[index].category)
}
```

Comment: а можете подсказать - как можно вывести полученное значение category вне цикла ? например сейчас у меня при выполнении succes из аякс-запроса в консоль выводит category дважды.

Comment: Можно на success посмотреть ?

Comment: да, конечно, дополнил свой код в вопросе.

Comment: так, он каждый выводит дважды ? или вам просто надо чтобы в одном alert выводил оба ?

Comment: у меня по нажатию кнопку вызывается success с алертом. и выходит так, что alert выводит - Wear - по нажатию на кнопку один раз. по нажатию снова - alert: 'Wear', 'Hats'.

Comment: var result = ''; category_list.forEach(function(item) {result += item.descr + '\n' }); alert(result); Я надюсь, что правильно вас понял

Answer (score 1):

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.category);
});
```

Вместо `console.log` можете использовать любую нужную вам функцию